# Eliminating rows and plotting a "customer country count in percentage" (Pandas, matplotlib)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

If this is the dataframe

```
VisitorID   visitNumber   Country
   1            1          USA
   2            1          UK
   3            1          CANADA
   3            2          CANADA
   4            1          MEXICO
```

I want to plot a piechart with matplotlib about the visitors of each country (so it'd be 33% for each country), so I don't want to count canada twice (because it has the same VisitorID)

I've been looking for hours and I can't get the solution.

I've tried:

```
df2 = df.groupby('VisitorID').agg({'visitNumber': 'max'}).reset_index()
```

but is deleting the other columns and I can't even see the shape anymore
If I try to run:

```
df2.shape()
```

the output is :

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the aggregation function for `Country` as well:

```
df2 = df.groupby('VisitorID').agg({'visitNumber': 'max', 'Country': 'first'}).reset_index()
```

Also `shape` is a property, not a method. So remove the parenthesis:

```
df2.shape
```